# how to enforce CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

two css files are used in a program : `file1.css` and `file2.css`.

In file1.css one of the entry is

`ul { list-style: block; }`

which is not allowing list behave as it's intended (default behavior). In my file, I need both css files mentioned above , but I want `ul li` to work as default (ie bullet-ed list one below each other) can you please suggest how can I achieve same ?

Comment: ul { list-style : block; } is incorrect. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to override back to default.. you can use:

```
body ul { list-style:initial;}
body ul { list-style:disc outside none;} /* for ie also */
```

Comment: No need for that `body` tag. If `file2.css` is included *after* `file1.css` just `ul { ... }` will suffice.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `initial` property is [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

Comment: I added above mentioned line in file2.css ; but there is no change in the result.

Comment: maybe you have the same rule applying to the 'li' tag as well?

Comment: @DavidRandall you're right, for support in IE also, reset the style manually, I have edited above

Answer (score 1):

You can make the present css of `ul` more specific related to the particular block and mention the default css for `ul` in your css. This should solve your problem.

Comment: current file is very generic and data come from external source; I've control only on CSS to ensure UL and LI get's it's default display behavior.  I tried option mentioned below "list-style:initial;" but still there is no change.